# How to display raster layer in umn mapserver clearly

Tags: mapserver, umn-mapserver, umn

In my example the raster layer is not displaying in the correct color. When the layer is zoom in it is displaying in the correct color. Please check my code. Please tell me if anything should be added. My map is displayed in one rectangular box. If the zoomed map is fit in to that box completely then the original color is appearing. I can't understand the problem. Please inform me if any information of my example is required if anything is missing to solve the problem. It would be highly helpful to me.
Thank you.

### gardenmap.map:

```
          MAP 
           NAME GMAP_DEMO 
  STATUS ON 
 SIZE 400 300 
SYMBOLSET ../etc/symbols.txt 
EXTENT 688649.375 2983133.5 693946.3125 2986990 
UNITS METERS 

SHAPEPATH "../data" 
IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255 
FONTSET ../etc/fonts.txt 
    # 
  # Start of web interface definition  
   # 
  WEB 
 MINSCALE 5000 
 MAXSCALE 700000 
  IMAGEPATH "/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/" 
 IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/" 
  END 


  # 
   # Start of legend 
  # 
 LEGEND 
 KEYSIZE 18 12 
  LABEL 
   TYPE BITMAP 
   SIZE MEDIUM 
  COLOR 0 0 89 
END 
STATUS ON 
  END 

  # 
 # Start of scalebar 
 # 
      SCALEBAR 
  IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255 
  LABEL 
  COLOR 0 0 0 
   SIZE SMALL 
  END 
  SIZE 150 5 
  COLOR 255 255 255 
   BACKGROUNDCOLOR 0 0 0 
       OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0 
   UNITS kilometers 
       INTERVALS 5 
      STATUS ON 
      END 
  
    LAYER 
       NAME lissiv 
      METADATA 
           "DESCRIPTION" "garden_ms" 
      END 
        TYPE RASTER 
      STATUS ON 
        DATA lissiv.tif 
            OFFSITE 0 0 0 
        PROCESSING "BANDS=1,2,3" 
       PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO" 
         PROCESSING "DITHER=YES" 
        PROCESSING "LUT=50:90,60:100,70:120" 
         PROCESSING "NODATA=22" 
         END
END#mapfile
```